# Why can't the box element be created?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am suppose to create a box using JS code.
I am trying to create the box via JS code and minimal HTML and CSS code.

When I render it, nothing appears, it is just a blank page. I was able to make a button appear if I add the button element via HTML code, however I am trying to do this with JS instead

```js
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.id = 'btn';
btn.innerHTML = 0;
document.body.appendChild(btn);
btn.addEventListener("click," function() {
    btn.innerHTML ++
});
```

There is suppose to be a box that has a start value of 0. When the box is clicked, it increments. However there is no box appearing.

Comment: try modifying your code to btn.id = 'myBtn' ; btn.setAttribute('class','btn btn-default'); and see if i starts appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var btn = document.createElement('button');
btn.id = 'btn';
btn.innerHTML = 0;
document.body.appendChild(btn);
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    btn.innerHTML ++
});
```

You need to put coma after **"click"**, there is a syntactical error in your code

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you for the help dude. Wasted an hour trying to figure out what went wrong.